# Python got back to beging start

Tags: python, speech-recognition

Is there a reason why my script won't go back to start. I want to go back to the beginning of this file when omxprocess is done in the command line I just get have a nice day ;) when the file is done playing. Is there a way to get it to go back to start and loop this file?

```
import re
import os
import sys
import subprocess
import re
import speech_recognition as sr
from os import path
from pydub import AudioSegment
import time

def start():
    # transcribe audio file
    AUDIO_FILE = "test.wav"

    # use the audio file as the audio source
    r = sr.Recognizer()
    with sr.AudioFile(AUDIO_FILE) as source:
        audio = r.record(source)  # read the entire audio file

    # print(r.recognize_google(audio)) 
    #END AUDIO TRANSCRIBE

 def string_found(string1, string2):
    return re.search(r"\b" + re.escape(string1) + r"\b", string2)

 def find_words(text, words):
    return [word for word in words if string_found(word, text)]

 keyword = str(r.recognize_google(audio))
 sentences = (keyword)
 search_keywords=[ 'theme', 'son', 'serial','bonnie','cereal']
 print (sentences)

 found = find_words(sentences, search_keywords)
 name = re.sub('\W+','', str(found))
 print (name)
 #print(name.strip('mo'))
 # Open the file for reading
 with open('input.txt') as fd:

    # Iterate over the lines
    for line in fd:

        # Capture one-or-more characters of non-whitespace after the initial match
        match = re.search(rf'.*{name}.* : (\S+)', line)
        print (match)
        # Did we find a match?
        if match:
            # Yes, process it
            music = match.group(1)
            print('{}'.format(music))
           # omxprocess = subprocess.Popen(['omxplayer', '-olocal', music],  stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=None, stderr=None, bufsize=0)
            time.sleep(5)
           # omxprocess.stdin.write(b'q')
start()
```

Comment: Do you mean you want to perform the function start again?

Comment: Yes if that will run through the entire script again

Answer (score 0):

This did it, I need to add a start() to my if match statement

```
import re
import os
import sys
import subprocess
import re
import speech_recognition as sr
from os import path
from pydub import AudioSegment
import time

def start():
    # transcribe audio file
    AUDIO_FILE = "test.wav"

    # use the audio file as the audio source
    r = sr.Recognizer()
    with sr.AudioFile(AUDIO_FILE) as source:
        audio = r.record(source)  # read the entire audio file

    # print(r.recognize_google(audio)) 
    #END AUDIO TRANSCRIBE

 def string_found(string1, string2):
    return re.search(r"\b" + re.escape(string1) + r"\b", string2)

 def find_words(text, words):
    return [word for word in words if string_found(word, text)]

 keyword = str(r.recognize_google(audio))
 sentences = (keyword)
 search_keywords=[ 'theme', 'son', 'serial','bonnie','cereal']
 print (sentences)

 found = find_words(sentences, search_keywords)
 name = re.sub('\W+','', str(found))
 print (name)
 #print(name.strip('mo'))
 # Open the file for reading
 with open('input.txt') as fd:

    # Iterate over the lines
    for line in fd:

        # Capture one-or-more characters of non-whitespace after the initial match
        match = re.search(rf'.*{name}.* : (\S+)', line)
        print (match)
        # Did we find a match?
        if match:
            # Yes, process it
            music = match.group(1)
            print('{}'.format(music))
           # omxprocess = subprocess.Popen(['omxplayer', '-olocal', music],  stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=None, stderr=None, bufsize=0)
            time.sleep(5)
           # omxprocess.stdin.write(b'q')
           start()
start()
```